# where to keep global variables and functions in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

i have some variables & functions in my project that i need in every page. The data in variables are coming from cookies & in functions i am calling some services to get the data.For now i am keeping them in some controller & using $rootScope for global access but this didn't work when i reload the page.So where should i keep these variables & functions?
Thanks in advance

This is the controller code-

```
pkController.controller('domainOneController', [
        '$scope',
        '$cookies',
        '$route',
        '$location',
        '$mdSidenav',
        '$rootScope',
        'domainService',
        'subDomainService',
        function($scope, $cookies, $route, $location, $mdSidenav, $rootScope,
                domainService, subDomainService) {
        /*getting username from cookies to display in dashboard & if not found then redirect to login page*/

        $rootScope.role = $cookies.get('role');
        $rootScope.userInfo = $cookies.get('login');
        $rootScope.id = $cookies.get('id');
        $rootScope.isSidenavOpen = false;

        if ($rootScope.userInfo == undefined
                || $rootScope.role == undefined) {
            $location.path("/");
        }
        $rootScope.$route = $route;

        /*for opening slider*/

        $rootScope.openSlider = function() {

            $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
        };

        /*getting sub-domains from service & showing sub-domains of first domain on page loading*/

        $scope.subDomains = subDomainService.getSubDomain(1);
        $scope.subDomains.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.subDomainNames = data.subdomains;

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });

        /*switching between pages by clicking on slider & updating sub-category*/

        $rootScope.redirect = function(id, domain) {

            $rootScope.pageTitle = domain; //changing page title while switching between domains

            $scope.subDomains = subDomainService.getSubDomain(id + 1);
            $scope.subDomains.success(
                    function(data, status, headers, config) {

                        $rootScope.subDomainNames = data.subdomains;

                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            });

            switch (id) {
            case 0:

                $location.path("/domain_one/dashboard");
                break;

            case 1:

                $location.path("/domain_two/dashboard");
                break;

            case 2:

                $location.path("/domain_three/dashboard");
                break;

            case 'myKpi':

                $location.path("/myKpi/dashboard");
                break;
            }

            $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
        };

        /*getting domains*/

        $rootScope.domainNames = [];
        $scope.domains = domainService.getDomain();
        $scope.domains.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $rootScope.pageTitle = data.domains[0].Domain.name; //setting page title

            for (var i = 0; i < data.domains.length; i++) {

                $rootScope.domainNames.push(data.domains[i].Domain.name);
            }

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });

    } ]);
```

This are html pages where i am using these variables and functions-

```
            <div layout="row" class="nav nav-stacked sliderMenu">
            <md-sidenav md-component-id="left" md-is-open="isSidenavOpen">
                <div layout="column" >
                    <md-button class="panel-button firstBlock" ng-click="openSlider()"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></md-button>
                    <md-button ng-repeat="domain in domainNames" ng-click="redirect($index,domain)" >{{domain}}</md-button>
                    <md-button ng-click="redirect('myKpi')">My Kpis</md-button>
                    <md-button class="upload">Upload</md-button>
                </div>
            </md-sidenav>
        </div>

<!-- Menu Slider Starts -->

<div

    <label>Subcategory : </label>
     <md-select  placeholder="All Category" ng-model="SubDomains">
        <md-option ng-repeat="(key,value) in subDomainNames" value="{{value}}">{{value}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not a factory?

Comment: This happens only when you reload the page... right ?
If yes, then make sure you have the variables saved in cookies (both before and after reload).
Anyway, I don't feel keeping it in rootScope is a good Idea.

Comment: i want to use these variables & functions in my html pages

Comment: @ShahRukhK yes this happens on reload & variables are already stored in cookies

Comment: "this didn't work when i reload the page"  If you want persistent data storage, you need a persistent storage method.  This means localStorage, cookies, or a serverside database.    Within an session you should use a service for globals rather than littering `rootScope`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For functions that are required across controllers**

You can use the following:

- Service
- Factory

**For storing variables that is required across controllers**

- You can store in localStorage or sessionStorage depending on the requirements.
  For example if you need data that should not be lost on closing the browser    tab etc. you should use localStorage

  *eg: storing wishlist in ecommerce website without login you use localStorage, so that when user later returns, wishlist data can be seen*
- You can also use services to store common variables and access them inside controllers dynamically at runtime. 
  Note: here the variable data might be lost on refresh unless you are storing it at the backend and making API call on every refresh

Comment: thanx for ur answer.. i found it helpful

Comment: but if i add functions in services then how can i call those functions from my html pages?

Comment: You need to call those functions from your controller by injecting services into the controller. You can wrap that particular call in a function that can be called from the html

Comment: and if my htmls are partials?

Comment: If they are partials they should have controllers assigned to it. To those controllers you can inject the service you need.

Answer (score 0):

Storing variables in `$rootScope` is not a good idea since the data is not available upon refreshing so you can make use of browser's `local storage` or `session storage` for storing variables and also you can use libraries like `ngStorage` (https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) for better handling. As for functions, angular service would be good.

> More info on using angular providers can be found here:
>   https://gist.github.com/demisx/9605099

Answer (score 0):

I often step outside of the strict "MVC" model and define a singleton object, called `globals` *(I'm so imaginative ...)*, which is defined in a JS file that is included by anyone that needs it.  This object has `load()` and `save()` methods which interact with local-storage. *(The object will only actually "load itself" once, even if asked to do so many times.)* Each client is obliged to at some point call `save()`. *(Trying to do this in a destructor produced timing issues.)*

All of the "globals" that exist throughout the application are defined as properties of this singleton object. *(Even if they are not actually "saved.")* This makes it explicit and obvious exactly what "this application's 'global' values" *are.* It makes it obvious precisely where references to them can be found in the source-code.

It also *centralizes* the duty of persisting the globals (as necessary) to local storage. No other part of the application ever refers to local storage directly. This object also detects the situation where the user has *turned off* local storage, e.g. through "private browsing" modes, and generates an appropriate warning.)

This self-discipline has paid off many times in producing applications that are straightforward to debug.

We simply "rolled our own" logic when creating this.